# Adding mbtiles file to TileMill?

Tags: tiles, tilemill

Is it possible to add a mbtiles file as TileMill layer?

Answer (score 5):

It is currently not possible to add mbtiles to TileMill.  You're best bet is to use one or more GeoTIFFs instead.

http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/16-can-you-add-mbtiles-to-an-existing-project